# Problem with interface

Tags: c#, interface

What is bad on this code? It is simple example:

```
class Program
{
    public interface IAccount
    {

    }

    public class Account :IAccount
    {

    }

    public static IAccount LogOn()
    {
        return new Account();
    }

    public class Avatar
    {
        public Account Cred { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var avatar = new Avatar();

        avatar.Cred = LogOn();
    }
}
```

I get compile error :

```
    Error   5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'console.Program.IAccount' to 'console.Program.Account'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BACKUP\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta
\Pokec__Messenger\console\Program.cs    35  27  console
```

What is it correct implementation. Thank for advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Avatar.Cred` property is of type `Account`, not `IAccount`... but `LogOn` is declared to return just `IAccount`. So it could return some other `IAccount` implementation - the compiler won't let you just assume that the `IAccount` will be an Account without an explicit cast.

Options:

- Change the type of the `Cred` property to `IAccount` instead of `Account`. This is probably best as it reduces the coupling between `Avatar` and `Account`, so you can use other implementations of `IAccount`.
- Change the return type of `LogOn` to `Account` instead of `IAccount`. This ties the `LogOn` *API* to `Account`, instead of just the *implementation*.
- Cast when you assign the property:

  ```
  avatar.Cred = (Account) LogOn();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Avatar
{
    public IAccount Cred { get; set; }
}
```